# NFS sharing Windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server-2008-r2, nfs

So i have to export a folder from windows server to linux using NFS sharing. I have already created the NFS on the windows side with no problems what so ever, this is how i created it:

```
 nfsshare mynfs=C:\nfs-sh -o anon=yes ro
```

When i click enter it appears that it was created sucessfully

However on the linux side, mounting the NFS share like this:

```
mount -t nfs xx.x.xx.xx:/mynfs /mnt/win-nfs
```

It doesn't show up any error but gives me permission denied error and input/output data errors when i try to get in the folder : win-nfs.

Did i mess anything up during the NFS Sharing creation on the windows server side?

Comment: You may need to add credentials. `username=pedro` to your mount options (even though anon is specified windows side). Or `-o defaults` Can su `ls /mnt/win-nfs`?

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.